# How to replace String using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm using Java and what I want to do is very simple :

- I want to get the second character of specific word,
- Test this character if it equals to 'a' replace it with 0, if equals to 'b' replace it with '1'
- The expression should be in one line (using regex)

Something like :

```
input = input.match(/^.(.)/) == "a" 
? input.replace(/^.(.)/, "0") : input.match(/^.(.{1})/) == "b" 
? input.replace(/^.(.)/, "1") : input
```

I want to know if there is any optimised and clean way to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no way to do that in 1 line with a Java regex because you need to replace a pattern with 2 different replacement strings and this text is missing from the match.

Comment: Why do many people do `.{1}`? What do you think is the difference to `.`

Comment: Why the odd requirement to use regex at all? There are much simpler ways to fetch the second letter of a string...

Comment: I'm not regex expert. So many thanks @Fallenhero I'll take your suggestion in consideration.

Comment: `s=s.substring(0,1)+s.substring(1, 2).replace("a", "0").replace("b", "1")+s.substring(2);` one liner, no need for regex. might not be the best solution

Comment: @TomLord because I have to put this expression in xml file.

Comment: So, you are stuck here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I really don't know if there is another way to achieve it :s

Comment: Yes, there is, but not a one-liner. `Matcher#appendReplacement` allows using a custom replacement for a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Do you think that I can easily make it in xml file ?

Comment: No, you need to modify the *code*.

Comment: My answer seems not to be what OP wanted.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ok, get your point.

Comment: @Fallenhero exactly, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you could try this.

```
input.replaceFirst(/^(.)a/, '$10').replaceFirst(/^(.)b/,'$11')
```

Meaning:
`^` start of string
`(.)` match 1 character and capture

Use that capture in the replacement

Comment: Actually, in Java you should use `replaceFirst("^(.)a", "$10").replaceFirst("^(.)b","$11")`

Comment: Oh right this was Java not JS. What is the difference to `replace`?

Comment: `replaceFirst` replaces the first occurrence only. Just to be consistent with the pattern. Otherwise, you might as well use `.replaceAll` (this is the equivalent of `/g` based JS pattern, as in `s.replace(/(.)./g, "$10")`).

Comment: Ah, I see Java will keep looking even if it already matched. That is the same behaviour as JS with flag `g`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Check with this code may be help you.

```
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("aqbcdefag");
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^(.)(a|b){1}.*");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.start()+"  :  "+m.group(2));
        if(m.group(2).toString().equals("a")){
            str.replace(1, 1, "0");
        }else if(m.group(2).toString().equals("b")){
            str.replace(1, 1, "1");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinod for you reply but what I want is regex expression or oneline code to put in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work:

```
str.replace(/^a/, "0").replace(/^b/, "1");
```